# How can I get a relative path from listed files?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm writing a method copies all files for specified `Path` to a local directory.

How can I get a relative path name from anyone of listed files?

```java
FileSystem fs = ...;

// remote directory whose files are copied from
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path path = new Path("/path/to/the/directory");

// local directory into which files are copied.
java.nio.file.Path directory = ...;

for (LocatedFileStatus status : fs.listFiles(path, true)) {

    // status: HdfsNamedFileStatus{path=hdfs://.../path/to/the/directory/.../...; ...}
    // status.getPath(): hdfs://.../path/to/the/directory/.../...

    // How can I get a relative path name for each status
    // against the source path
    // so that I can createDirectories on the target directory?

    // I need the .../... part from hdfs://.../path/to/the/directory/.../...
    // so that I can call Files.createDirectories(directory.resolve(.../...))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
public FileStatus[] listStatus(Path p)
```

To get the contents of a directory.